# Raspberry pi running arch linux connected to two different wan ports(wifi and ethernet) I want to disable intenet access and keep local access

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, ethernet

I have a unique setup I think. I have a raspberry pi running pikvm. I have two internet connections at home (Xfinity and ATT):

- xfinity connected via --> ethernet port (MAIN)
- ATT connected vis --> Wifi (second using as backup)

1. I want to stop all internet traffic and only allow local traffic to this device (without having to use router application)
2. I want to able to isolate Ethernet from Wi-Fi. I don't want them to know that the other exists. This way they are on their own and only accessible.

Can anyone help?

**What I have tried so far**.

After applying this setting I am still able to ping google.com. I have disable internet access to both of these devices via the att and xfinity routers. but it doesn't seem to stop ipv6 pinging.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 67:68 --sport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 10.0.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p udp  --m multiport --dports 1 - 65535 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --match multiport --dports 1:65535 -j DROP
```